# In Visual Studio Code, how can I get # to be auto replaced with #{} in Ruby strings

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code, how can I get # to be auto replaced with #{} in Ruby double quoted strings.

An 'autocorrect' function would do this but I don't think this is available in VS Code.

Other editors - Sublime, Atom, IntellIJ seem to have this 'out of the box'

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but there are plenty of really good ruby editors out there that are superior to Visual Studio. Rubymine is an IDE if you want to stay that route. Atom, Sublime, and TextMate are the most common editors. They're all great for Ruby dev.

Comment: @Dbz I believe the question is about Visual Studio Code, which is closer to Atom, Sublime, or TextMate and also has extensions for Ruby development

Comment: @Ross Attrill, Can you clairify what you mean by "auto replace"? Is it: when you type `#` in a string, `#{}` is automatically inserted?

Comment: Where have you searched and what did you find? What did you try? "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: @Matt - yes - I am looking for behaviour exactly as you describe.

Comment: @theTinMan - I don't believe that it is easily achieved - hence the question to see if anybody has cracked this.   However, I will edit the question.

Comment: @dbz - Yes - I am aware of all those editor and have used them all at different times.   I am finding Visual Studio Code to be the best current editor in many other ways.   RubyMine / IntelliJ is great but sometimes too heavy.

Comment: I came here for the same reason, once you try the honey...you get addicted.
basically this could be done with a user snippet, but it requires context. When pressing #, the snippet should be triggered Only within " and " to become "..#{<cursor_here>}..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a Visual Studio Code extension called 'Auto Add Brackets in String Interpolation' by 'Ali Ariff'.  It provides the required functionality.

The extension is available at: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliariff.auto-add-brackets